# Reasoning behind choosing an EKS node instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I use EKS

Curious to know how to choose what instance type (for EKS node) I'd need for my application.

Number of pods should be considered? Just trying to find any info on this as I am not sure where to start really for deciding on a particular instance type.

Comment: We can't really answer this without more information about your application? Is it an AI so that GPU boxes are better, or a real-time database that needs great storage IOPS?

Answer (score 0):

The best bet is to start off small and build up from there. One of the awesome things about Kubernetes is that [swapping out the nodes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/update-workers.html) for bigger or smaller instances is fairly easy.

Some things that would inform your decision are:

- Do your applications require special hardware such as GPUs or Inferentia Chips?
- What are the resource requirements for your largest applications?
- How many pods of each application are you hoping to run (minimum of 3 per service is good)?
- Would you prefer a high density of pods (lots of pods on one node) for lower costs overall; or have pods more spread out on more nodes for higher availability?

Having said that, bear in mind that there are limitations to the maximum number of pods per node - which is constrained by the [max number or elastic IPs of the instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI). There is also some IPs that are reserved by the instance and system pods so the number is a little less than what's prescribed there.